# ¿Cuál exactamente podría ser el error en este método que NetBeans no me lo menciona hasta que lo ejecuto?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, bucle-for, java-8

soy bastante nuevo en todo lo que es la programación en general pero quería intentar comenzar por Java. Total estaba intentado hacer una función que ingrese dos cadenas de texto y las combine entre si, siendo que la mayor comenzara primero. ejemplo: cadenaUno: "Uno", cadenaDos: "El" = UEnlo.
Sin embargo a simple vista no veo nada fuera de lo normal en mi código (como novato digo) y netbeans no lo detecta hasta que lo corre. Qué podría estar haciendo mal? de antemano muchas gracias por cualquier tipo de ayuda y perdón si lo que muestro como código es un frankestein!

```
public String MetodoCadenasEntrelazadas(){
  String mensaje = "";  
  String indicadorDeFinalización = "tarea realizada";
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
  System.out.println("Ingrese la primera palabra");
  String cadenaUno = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Ingrese la segunda palabra");
  String cadenaDos= sc.nextLine();
 
 int suma = cadenaUno.length()+cadenaDos.length();
  if( cadenaUno.length()>cadenaDos.length() ){
  for(int i=1;i<suma;i++)
  mensaje += cadenaUno.charAt(i)+cadenaDos.charAt(i);
  }
  else{
  for(int i=1; i<suma; i++ )
  mensaje += cadenaDos.charAt(i)+cadenaUno.charAt(i);
  }
  return indicadorDeFinalización;
```

Comment: Qué quieres decir con que "no lo detecta hasta que lo corre"?

Comment: Pues que de alguna manera el error no se muestra como algún error de sintaxis o algo por el estilo, simplemente da un error de "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2"

Comment: Netbeans y cualquier IDE solo detecta errores de compilación (errores de sintaxis). Es imposible detectar todos los errores que pueden ocurrir en tiempo de ejecución de un programa. Tienes que investigar que significa ese error `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` y analizar tu código para determinar que puedes estar haciendo mal.

Comment: es un problema logico.. charAt(i) es la posicion i dentro de tu cadena de caracteres.. pero tu for va de 1 (deberia ir de 0) a la suma de las dos cadenas.. y vos, no queres eso.. porque si una cadena mide 3, el elemento 4 no existe.. asi que lo que hay ahi, no es un error que netbeans vaya a encontrar, porque no es un error de codigo, es un error de logica en tu programacion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como respuesta a tu pregunta de ¿que podrias estar haciendo mal?. Lo que pasa es que en algún momento de la ejecucion del bucle-for el valor de i es **mayor** a la longitud de la cadena, por eso muestra el error.

Ahora respecto al error, es por que el error **"StringIndexOutOfBoundsException"** es un error del tipo *"Error en tiempo de Ejecución"* y el porque Neatbeans no lo muestra es porque, neatbeans y todos los otros IDE solo detectan los *"Errores en tiempo de Compilación"*. [si quieres saber mas sobre los tipos de errores haz clic aqui.](https://es.acervolima.com/tipos-de-errores-en-java-con-ejemplos/)

Y con respecto a tu codigo he tratado de refactorizarlo para que sea mas sencillo, entendible y que evite el error que mencionas. Aqui te lo dejo

```
public String metodoCadenasEntrelazadas() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Ingrese la primera palabra\t");
    String cadenaUno = sc.next();
    System.out.print("Ingrese la segunda palabra\t");
    String cadenaDos = sc.next();

    /* Asigna la cadena mayor y menor de acuerdo a una condición*/
    String cadenaMayor = (cadenaUno.length() > cadenaDos.length()) ? cadenaUno : cadenaDos;
    String cadenaMenor = (cadenaMayor.equals(cadenaUno)) ? cadenaDos : cadenaUno;

    String cadenasEntrelazadas = "";
    
    /* Recorre la cadena de mayor longitud */
    for (int i = 0; i < cadenaMayor.length(); i++) {
        cadenasEntrelazadas += cadenaMayor.charAt(i);
        /* Añader caracter de la cadena menor solo si el valor de i es menor a la longitud de la cadena */
        if (i < cadenaMenor.length()) 
            cadenasEntrelazadas += cadenaMenor.charAt(i);
    }
    return cadenasEntrelazadas;
}
```